# Apple Warning ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage received

Tags: uiwebview, wkwebview, itms-90809

I received a warning from Apple that I would use UIWebView API: "Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs".

Problem is that I only use WKWebViews. It is a native app with a couple of dependencies. But no hybrid app.
If I search my project for UIWebView I don't find anything. How can I ensure that I do not use UIWebview?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a framework I use. Put it into an disassembler and found UIWebView references...

Comment: how to identify it